# PowerShell regular expression to interpret time strings 12h34m56s with optional groups

Tags: regex, powershell, grouping

Using PowerShell and regex, I'm trying to interpret a time string in a data file, the string is for example `12h30m` meaning 12 hours and 30 minutes, or `15m` meaning 15 minutes, `1m30s`, `2h` etc. I figured I could split these strings using regex to separate the hours minutes and seconds, and only get the digits parts, so leave out the `h`, `m`, `s`, and then do some calculations.

However, I managed to get a regex working but only when I also include the `h`, `m`, `s`, I mean when I add a "positive look ahead" part in the regex then the final result is not what I expected.

Here is the PowerShell script

```
$input = "12h34m56s"
#$input = "4h30m"
#$input = "1m15s"
#$input = "14400"

Write-Output "--(test 1)--------------------"
$input -match '(\d*h)?(\d*m)?(\d*s)?(\d*)?'
Write-Output $Matches

Write-Output "--(test 2)--------------------"
$input -match '(\d*(?=h))?(\d*(?=m))?(\d*(?=s))?(\d*)?'
Write-Output $Matches
```

The output is this:

```
--(test 1)--------------------
True

Name                           Value
----                           -----
4
3                              56s
2                              34m
1                              12h
0                              12h34m56s
--(test 2)--------------------
True
4
1                              12
0                              12
```

The first part "test 1" is what I expected, however for the second part "test 2" I was expecting this output

```
--(test 2)--------------------
True

Name                           Value
----                           -----
4
3                              56
2                              34
1                              12
0                              12h34m56s
```

I tested this [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/o6AgaM/1) and looking at the syntax coloring it *seems* correct, but at he top it states "27 matches" and I would expect just 5 matches (because 5 lines). So I suspect it has something to do with grouping. I tried adding extra parenthesis around the whole but that didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: regex time string interpretation]

Comment: `-match` in your code returns *the first* match only. A regex101, you see *all matches*.

Comment: Ah ok, but if the first test is one match, then why is the second test multiple matches?

Comment: There are always as many groups in the result as there are capturing groups in the pattern + 1 (for the overall match).

Comment: As an aside: don't use `$input` for custom purposes, it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) managed by PowerShell.

Comment: are you mainly looking to this with regex for learning or why are you not converting your input string into a `TimeSpan`? `[timespan]::ParseExact('12h34m56s', 'hh\hmm\mss\s', $null)`

Comment: To extend @SantiagoSquarzon's comment, if you want to support multiple patterns you can use the ```ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider)``` overload - e.g. ```[timespan]::ParseExact($timestring, [string[]] @("hh\hmm\mss\s", "mm\mss\s"), $null)``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-8.0#system-timespan-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon TimeSpan wouldn't work because the format has optional groups, so you'd still have to interpret if the string value contains `hour/minute` or `minute/second` or just `hour` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`[timespan]::ParseExact()`** as shown in the other, helpful answers, is **definitely preferable if/once you have individual tokens representing timespans**.

However, **at least hypothetically you may (first) have to extract such tokens *out of a larger text***, in which case a regex *is* needed - see below.

---

The **problem with your regex** is that using lookahead assertions (e.g, `(?=h)`) prevents your regex from recognizing tokens such as `12h34m56s` as a *single* match, because lookaround assertions do not *consume* the substrings they match.

Therefore, just match those characters directly, and enclose the subexpression in `(?:…)`, i.e. a *non-capturing* group to avoid unnecessary capture groups; e.g., instead of `(\d*h)?`, use `(?:(\d+)h)?`.

Also note the use of `+` instead of `+`, as at least *one* digit should be present, whereas the subexpression *as a whole* may be absent (`(?:…)?`)

To put it all together, along with using *named* capture groups, which makes it easier to identify which capture-group matches captured what units:

```
$str = @'
12h34m56s545294385
1h2m3s
4h30m
1m15s
14400
'@

[regex]::Matches($str, '(?:(?<hrs>\d+)h)?(?:(?<mins>\d+)m)?(?:(?<secs>\d+)s)?(?<num>\d+)?') |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Value) { # Only consider nonempty matches.
      [pscustomobject] @{ 
        Match = $_.Value
        Groups = $_.Groups | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object Name, Value | Out-String
      } 
    }
  } | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Output:

```
Match              Groups
-----              ------
12h34m56s545294385
                   Name Value
                   ---- -----
                   hrs  12
                   mins 34
                   secs 56
                   num  545294385
                  
                  
1h2m3s            
                   Name Value
                   ---- -----
                   hrs  1
                   mins 2
                   secs 3
                   num
                  
                  
4h30m             
                   Name Value
                   ---- -----
                   hrs  4
                   mins 30
                   secs
                   num
                  
                  
1m15s             
                   Name Value
                   ---- -----
                   hrs
                   mins 1
                   secs 15
                   num
                  
                  
14400             
                   Name Value
                   ---- -----
                   hrs
                   mins
                   secs
                   num  14400
```

Comment: You're right, even though using `TimeSpan` is the better solution overall, I'll accept this one as it answers the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Fine if you want to do this with regex and you're probably expecting a regex answer but future readers should be aware this should be done using [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-8.0#system-timespan-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider)).

Note, casting `[string[]]` is required while calling this overload.

```bash
$formats = [string[]]@(
    'hh\hmm\mss\s'
    'h\hmm\m'
    'm\mss\s'
)

$inputStrings = @(
    '12h34m56s'
    '4h30m'
    '1m15s'
    '14400'
)

$inputStrings | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -notmatch '\D') {
        return [timespan]::FromSeconds($_)
    }

    [timespan]::ParseExact($_, $formats, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
}
```

Comment: Worth calling out that the ```[string[]]``` cast is required - either on the ```$formats = [string[]] ...``` variable assignment or in the function call ```[timespan]::ParseExact($_, [string[]] $formats, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)``` otherwise I think PowerShell stringifies the array and calls the ```ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider)``` overload, which will fail if there's more than one item in the ```$formats``` (it'll still work if there's only one item because the stringified vallue is the same as the item value)

Comment: @mclayton I think you're right there, if passing formats as `[object[]]` seems like it tries to call the `string, string, IFormatProvider` overload. Something very similar happens with `datetime.ParseExact`

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful answer, I didn't know you could `ParseExact` with a TimeSpan and multiple formats. The only exception edge-case it doesn't take into account when the input is only digits, then it should be interpreted as seconds, not `hhmms`

Comment: @BdR oh `14400` was only seconds? I thought it was `14h 40m 0s` lol my bad

Comment: Just to labour the point, from experimenting just now it seems ```[TimeSpan]::ParseExact("12h34m56s xxx", @("hh\hmm\mss\s'", "xxx'"), $null);``` gives the same result as ```[TimeSpan]::ParseExact("12h34m56s xxx", "hh\hmm\mss\s' xxx'"), $null);``` so it's definitely preferring to stringify the ```@( ... )``` and call ```ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider)``` in the absence of a ```[string[]]``` cast :-)

Comment: @mclayton `[datetime]::ParseExact('03/24/2023', ('MM/', 'dd/', 'yyyy'), $null, 2)` about the same for this one too :)

Answer (score 3):

As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834505/powershell-regular-expression-to-interpret-time-strings-12h34m56s-with-optional#comment133767102_75834505) commented, you can use the `[timespan]::ParseExact()` method on a number of formats.
In your case, the only snag is when the string contains digits only, in that case use the `[timespan]::new()` constructor and multiply the numeric value of the string by 10000000 to convert the seconds to Ticks:

```
$timeString = '1m15s'
if ($timeString -match '\D') {
    # try ParseExact using the following formats
    $formats =  'h\h','h\hm\ms\s','h\hm\mss\s','h\hmm\m','h\hmm\ms\s','h\hmm\mss\s',
                'hh\h','hh\hmm\m','hh\hmm\ms\s','hh\hmm\mss\s',
                'm\m','m\ms\s','m\mss\s','mm\m','mm\ms\s','mm\mss\s','s\s','ss\s'
    [timespan]::ParseExact($timeString, [string[]]$formats, $null)
}
else {
    # only digits, return a new timespan using the Ticks constructor
    [timespan]::new([long]$timeString * 10000000)
    # or use 
    # [timespan]::FromSeconds([double]$timeString)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use this, it seems like a better method than using the regex